# Swift UICollectionView jumps and stutters when loading images with kingfisher in CellForRowAt

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewdelegate

So I am loading in pictures related to posts for my new social app similar to IG, I am using kingfisher to load my images async.

The problem is when using the 'CellForRowAt' delegate method is that the image loading is jumpy and glitchy and the user never has a smooth scroll experience.

```
let imageURL = URL(string: "\(post.images.first?.imageUrl ?? "")\(post.images.first?.fileName ?? "")")
        currentCell.ImageViewContentIndicator.image = UIImage(systemName: "photo")
        currentCell.ImagePreviewForContent.kf.indicatorType = .activity
        **currentCell.ImagePreviewForContent.kf.setImage(with: imageURL)**
```

The thumbnails load in fine, it is more or less how they are being loaded in. If anyone has any experience with this sort of thing id be grateful to hear your tips!

Comment: I wouldn't load the images within the `cellForRowAt` method.I would load the images "in anticipation" for the cells showing if you want a smooth experience.

Comment: @Eric for this tableview I actually fixed it inside the cellForRowAt. I am utilizing self-sizing cells, the problem i had was that my 'estimatedRowHeight' was too 'large' therefore the tableview was using already made cells. I realized my mistake and set the 'estimatedRowHeight' so low it forces the layout to be made every time.

Comment: @Eric for my collectionView cells i use the 'willDisplay' method because of fast scrolling. Perfectly smooth scrolling on all three pages.